# Cannot seek ahead in songs started by Windows Media Player, but can when played by WMP?

Tags: windows-7, mp3, music, windows-media-player, media-player

If I am in `Library > Music` in Windows Media Player and I double-click a song or album, it starts playing, but I cannot skip ahead in the song. Clicking the seek bar restarts the song. However, when I start playing a song from Windows Explorer, I can seek fine. Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the tag, I assume that these are MP3 files? This issue usually happens when the length of the files isn't present in WMP's library. A possible way to fix this is by re-adding the files to library.

Select the files, right-click, `Delete` - `Delete from library only` - `OK`. Then go to `Tools` - `Advanced` and select `Restore deleted library items` (press Ctrl+M if you don't see the Tools menu).

Comment: I'll try it when I get home.

Comment: Don't remember how I fixed this. I think it was something to do with the files themselves not having permissions for WMP to read the metadata or something, so I moved all my music to `C:\Users\Public\Music`. This is a good solution that probably would have worked though.